# SingleChildScrollView not keeping scroll position

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `SingleChildScrollView` widget in my app that contains a `Column` as a child.

The `Column` has many children and the last one in the very bottom of the scrolled screen is a `StreamBuilder` that I use to change a child `Image`

The issue is that when I tap on the image, the logic of the StreamBuilder works and the image is changed, but then the SingleChildScrollView scrolls a bit up so that the image is not visible and forces the user to scroll down again to be able to see the new loaded image.

```
Widget _buildScroll() => SingleChildScrollView(
child: Container(
  width: 2080,
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      _buildTopBar(),
      _buildMainContent(),
      SizedBox(height: 30),
      Container(
        child: Image.asset(
          "assets/images/chart_legend.png",
          width: 300,
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 30),
      Image.asset("assets/images/road_map.png", width: 600),
      StreamBuilder<int>(
          initialData: 1,
          stream: _compareStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              if (snapshot.data == 1) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    child: Image.asset("assets/images/compare1.png"),
                    onTap: () => _compareSubject.add(2),
                  ),
                );
              } else if (snapshot.data == 2) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    child: Image.asset("assets/images/compare2.png"),
                    onTap: () => _compareSubject.add(3),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    child: Image.asset("assets/images/compare3.png"),
                    onTap: () => _compareSubject.add(1),
                  ),
                );
              }
            }
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Image.asset("assets/images/compare1.png"),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
            );
          }),
    ],
  ),
),
);
```

However, even more weird is that, once I have done tap on all images, they will be showed as expected without scrolling up...meaning that, if there is the second time i tap on a image, the second time the image is replaced the scrolling up in not happening.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that the size of your children changes and the `SingleChildScrollView` cannot handle that.

I think there could be two solutions that might work here:

- If you know the sizes of your images before they are loaded, you should enforce it using a `SizedBox`. This way, the scroll position will stay the same:

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: 300,
  height: 120,
  child: StreamBuilder<int>(...),
)
```

- Use [`ensureVisible`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPosition/ensureVisible.html) that you trigger once the stream builder is updated, which lets you control exactly where the image should be displayed.
  You would need to assign a [`ScrollController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html) to your [`SingleChildScrollView` (`controller` parameter)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView/controller.html). Then, you also need a [`GlobalKey`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) for your `StreamBuilder` that you want to show (`key` parameter).
  If you have saved instances of the two to variables, you will be able to call the following once your image is loaded:

```dart
scrollController.position.ensureVisible(
  globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject(),
  alignment: 0.5, // Aligns the image in the middle.
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 120), // So it does not jump.
);
```

Comment: another great answer by you, Thanks!, I just tested the first option, with the SizedBox since I am a bit in a hurry and looked like the easiest and fastest...worked very well.